# STM32F103CB timer not accurate

Tags: timer, interrupt, stm32f1, stm32cubemx

I'm new in stm32, I recently create a project to make a quick pulse on a GPIO pin every second, just to determine the time accuracy by the logic analyzer, however, I always get the time around 0.999,935s instead of one second, I tried everything I searched on the internet, but nothing work, please give a help.

My code was mostly generated by STM32CubeMX, these are the configs of CubeMX

[image: NVIC]

[image: TIM2]

[image: CLK config]

```
int main(void)

{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();

  MX_TIM2_Init();

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);

  while (1) { }

}

.
.
.

static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)

{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;

  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 799;

  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_DOWN;

  htim2.Init.Period = 9999;

  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;

  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;

  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)

  {

   Error_Handler();

  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;

  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)

  {

   Error_Handler();

  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;

  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;

  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)

  {

   Error_Handler();

  }

}

.
.
.

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)

{

  GPIOB->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_2 << 16u; // reset bit

}
```

[image: logic analyzer]

The time between 2 and 3 is always around 0.999935s
how can I fix this error to exactly one second???

Comment: are you sure that oscillogram is error free? I am sure that it is not

Comment: I'm using logic analyzer, it can determined stuff to nano second

Comment: I think you do not know the difference between resolution and precision